# ng-click not working inside ng-switch

Tags: angularjs, filter

I'm beginner with AngularJs, and i have a lot of questions :/

Here's one of them :

I have links that i use to filter data. So when i click on link one, the value for the filter `myFilter` is one, etc.

Just to show you that my filters work, i putted two times the links (see here http://plnkr.co/edit/2G6mahkmyIixMJ1mEVKp?p=preview)

In the above links, i use ng-swich, cause i want, when i click on a link, to remove the link and only keep the text

In the bottom links, there are no `ng-swich`, so `myFilter` works perfectly

Is it possible, to make the `ng-click` inside the `ng-swich` work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are approaching the issue involves far too much code duplication.

Also it is a bad practice to replace objects directly in the html. If you use a function bound to the scope it is cleaner and you won't run into child scope issues as much

Rather than creating four `<ul>` you could simply use `ng-if` within each `<li>` and use only one `<ul>`. This would also be a good case to create a very simple directive

HTML

```
<li>
     <span ng-if="myFilter.trimestre==1">Avril - juin</span>
     <a ng-if="myFilter.trimestre!=1" ng-click="updateFilter('trimestre',1)" href="#">Avril - juin</a>
</li>
```

JS

```
$scope.myFilter={};
$scope.updateFilter = function(key, val){
    $scope.myFilter[key]=val;
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/G2suxZYnr4T0ONAphJnP?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. I'm totally a beginner in angularJs, what do you mean by "use a function bound to the scope..." do you have an example ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: see function in my answer